# AngularJS, migrate from directive to component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, components, directive

I'm  trying to add a component instead of a directive but it doesn't work.
my directive:

```
    (function() {
    'use strict'; 
    angular.
        module('eventeditor')
        .directive("displayTab",
            function() {
                return({
                    templateUrl: function(elem, attr){
                        if(attr.tabname === 'details') return "/organizer/fragments/detailsform.html";
                    }
                });
            }
        );
    })();
```

Component style:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular.
    module('eventeditor')
    .component("displayTab", {
        templateUrl: function($element, $attrs) {
            if ($attrs.tabname === 'details') return "/organizer/fragments/detailsform.html";
        }
    });

})();
```

What am I doing wrong?
I use my template like:

```
<div ng-switch="nav.getTab()">
    <div ng-switch-when="details" display-tab="" tabname="details">details</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you see any error on your browser console? How do you use the directive/component in your template?

Comment: @ShuheiKagawa no any errors. Now I add how I use my template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components work only on element names while directives default to element names and attribute names.

```
<div ng-switch="nav.getTab()">
    <display-tab ng-switch-when="details" tabname="details">details</display-tab>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it works! But now there is another problem. <display-tab type="simple-input" name="name" label="Event Name" model="model.details.name" error="model.errors.details.name"></display-tab>. I want get data from model, but I get empty input value, why? In component I add bindings

Comment: What does your bindings look like? Also, how do you show the data in the component's template?

Comment: bindings look like: bindings: {
                        type: '@',
                        name: '@',
                        label: '@',
                        model: '=',
                        error: '=',
                        options: '=',
                        changefunction: '='
                    }, in template I show data like I did it when use directive: <display-tab type="simple-input" name="name" label="Event Name" model="model.details.name" error="model.errors.details.name"></display-tab>

Comment: It my template input <div>
    <div>
        <label class="form-name" for="{{name}}" >{{label}}</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div >
            <input type="text"
                   ng-model="model"
                   ng-class="{'fieldError' : error != null}"
                   id="{{name}}"
                   name="{{name}}"
            />
   <span ng-show="error" >{{error}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: Got it. With components, `controllerAs: '$ctrl'` is set by default. You'll need to do like `name="{{$ctrl.name}}"` in your component template.

Comment: I find problem. Problem was in chrome cache. In devTools it was necessary to 'Disable cache (while DevTools is open)' and now all right. Thank you for help.